# Nested For loop to create a flexbox grid, not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, flexbox

I am currently working on the odin project's Etch-A-Sketch project. I'm trying to create a flexbox grid of divs to fit inside my set container. My first attempt was a single for loop that created the enough divs based on the input being squared, but the flex wouldn't wrap properly. Instead of creating a 16x16 grid, it would make 15 across and then 17/18 down, with space on the right side and bottom of the container.

I decided to try a new method of creating a set number of row divs with the set number of column divs inside each row. I thought having a nested for loop to create the rows with the set number of columns inside each row would work, but currently it only makes one row with one column div. Can someone help me with what I am missing?

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
let col = document.createElement('div');
let row = document.createElement('div');

function createGrid(input) {
    for(i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        
        row.classList.add('row');
        containerEl.appendChild(row);

        for(j = 0; j < input; j++) {
            
            col.classList.add('col');
            row.appendChild(col);
        }
        
    }
}

col.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    col.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});

createGrid(16);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: burlywood;
    
}

#heading {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: brown;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px;
}

#container {
    background-color: white;
    height: 960px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading">Etch-A-Sketch</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: `row` and `col` should be declared inside the loop. Otherwise you're adding the same element over and over.

Comment: So I tried that and it didn’t create any divs. I declared them above each classList.

Comment: You also need to move the `addEventListener` call into the inner loop too.

Comment: Each call to `createElement()` creates a new element.   Calling `appendChild()` only places the element in the DOM.   If you call appendChild again on the same variable without creating a new element, it will just move the existing element.  ([see this](https://codepen.io/JasonGoemaat/pen/MWxmpOW))

Answer (score 1):

As Unmitigated commented, the rows and cols must be declared inside the loop (and the event listener too), like this:

```
const containerEl = document.getElementById('container');



function createGrid(input) {
    for(i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        
        let row = document.createElement('div');        
        row.classList.add('row');
        containerEl.appendChild(row);

        for(j = 0; j < input; j++) {
            
            let col = document.createElement('div');            
            col.classList.add('col');
            row.appendChild(col);
            col.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                col.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            });
        }
        
    }
}



createGrid(16);
```